# Ajuda em desenvolvimento web

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, pessoal!

Estou aprendendo a desenvolver websites e gostaria de uma ajuda, no site do editor que uso, atom, tem uma "animação" que eu achei fantástica. Segue o link do site: https://atom.io. No site vocês podem ver a animação.

O que eu gostaria de saber é como fazer uma animação dessas e o que devo estudar para aprender a fazer esse tipo de animação. Alguma API, Framework ???

Comment: Olá @GratefullyDead, Esse efeito é feito com CSS.
Você deve estudar CSS animation: [link do W3C, falando sobre](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), o efeito é feito usando 10 imagens (SVG) em diferentes velocidade de rotação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu dei uma olhada no site que você nos passou e visualizei como essa animação é realizada.

**Explicação sobre a animação**

Apesar de ser muito bonita, ela é bem simples de ser realizada. Nós temos aparentemente duas imagens. Sendo uma delas (a do círculo) formada por diversas imagens SVG em conjunto.

- Para que o "animal astronauta" se mova para cima e para baixo, foi utilizado o  seguinte comando CSS:

```css
animation: hero-octonaut 2s alternate ease-in-out infinite;
```

- Para os círculos que ficam girando, eles são um conjunto de arquivos SVG, onde cada um está rodando com, aparentemente, uma velocidade diferente. O comando CSS para isso é:

```css
animation: hero-logo-circle 1s linear infinite;
```

- Também foi utilizada, para diferenciar as velocidade, a propriedade `animation-duration`.

**Estudos**

Bem, acredito que você já saiba **HTML5**, mas caso não saiba comece por aí. Depois o **CSS3** e depois o **JavaScript**.

Para realizar um efeito semelhante em alguma aplicação, conseguirá apenas com **HTML5** e **CSS3**.

Pesquise por **CSS Animation**, **Keyframes** e por **Utilização de SVG com HTML5 e CSS3**.